# Nest JS - Issue writing Jest Test Case for a function returning Observable Axios Response

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, jestjs, nestjs

I am fairly new to NestJS + Typescript + RxJs tech stack. I am trying to write a unit test case using Jest for one of my functions but not sure if doing it correctly.

**component.service.ts**

```
public fetchComponents(queryParams) {
  const url = this.prepareUrl(queryParams);

  const data$ = this.httpService.get(url);

  return data$
    .pipe(map(({ data }) => data));
}
```

**component.sevice.spec.ts**

> Test case works and passes

```
describe('fetchComponents', () => {
  const query = {
    limit: 10,
    offset: 0
  };

  const result: AxiosResponse = {
    data: 'Components',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: {},
    config: {}
  };
  it('should return Dummy Data when called successfully', () => {
    componentService.prepareUrl = jest.fn();

    jest.spyOn(httpService, 'get').mockImplementation(() => of(result));

   componentService.fetchComponents(market, query)
    .subscribe(
      (res) => {
        expect(res).toEqual('Components');
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Can you please provide suggestions and pointers on how exactly I should test this function. Also without using Library like `marbel-rx`
I am not sure if I am testing it correctly. Is there something else also which I should test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `Observables` are asynchronous, you have to add the asynchronous `done` paramter and call `done()` after the `expect` that is executed last. Otherwise, jest will finish the test run after `subscribe()` is called without waiting for the execution of the asynchronous execution of `subscribe`'s callback. Try to make your test fail by for example by expecting `'Komponents'`. The test will not fail.

Also, I'd recommend to use `mockImplementationOnce` instead of `mockImplementation` when possible, to avoid implicitly reusing mock behaviors in later calls and therewith creating implicit dependencies.

```
it('should return Dummy Data when called successfully', done => {
// Add done parameter                                   ^^^^
  componentService.prepareUrl = jest.fn();

  jest.spyOn(httpService, 'get').mockImplementationOnce(() => of(result));
// Prefer mockImplementationOnce                   ^^^^

  componentService.fetchComponents(market, query)
    .subscribe(
      (res) => {
        expect(res).toEqual('Components');
        done();
//      ^^^^^^  Call done() when test is finished
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code review. I actually wrote a catchError() block in my code and was testing it by calling incorrect URL. Still, Jest was complaining about that piece of code not reachable. The moment I added `done()` callback, that piece of code became reachable in my test and now it's 100%. Super thanks